# How to fix a workspace in eclipse that does not open anymore?

Tags: eclipse, workspace

One of my workspaces in eclipse can't be opened anymore. The other workspaces work fine. How can I fix this? First I thought this is an eclipse problem, but since the other workspaces work fine, something must be wrong with the workspace.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Are there any errors in the .log file in the failing workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: did you try removing the .metadata folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover corrupted Eclipse workspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950476/how-to-recover-corrupted-eclipse-workspace)

Comment: No I didn`t get any error messages. After removing .metadata I could open the workspace and import the old projects again.

Answer (score 70):

Try this-->>Goto .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi and remove workbench.xmi file to solve this issue:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi.
```

Comment: I'd be more comforatble using the -clearPersistedState suggested by @Viktor Brešan.  While deleting this file worked for me, so did using the -clearPersistedState flag. Perhaps the flag does the same thing, but the resulting workspace.xmi files between the two approaches are significantly different.

Comment: workbench.xmi was located in another package but deleting it worked for me with Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0)

Comment: Worked for me with 2021-12

Answer (score 13):

For me, starting eclipse with `-clearPersistedState` flag helped.

Comment: Using a built in flag seems more appropriate than manually wiping a workspace file. And it addressed the unknown hang I had in just one of my workspaces.

Answer (score 5):

I am using maven project with eclipse kepler ,I had also faced the same problem(workspace was not opening),please follow the below steps it may work
(please shutdown your machine everyday properly to avoid such issue)

- Go to your workspace which you wanted to open(you might have multiple workspace)
- .metadata folder will be there inside workspace
- Delete this folder
- open eclipse(just click from you desktop/taskbar/start search eclipse and click)
- it will open the fresh one and import all your project as existing maven project
- clean and build the project
- if not maven project just import the project it will work

Answer (score 2):

ty! the  -clearPersistedState flag helped.
How I did, i open in powershell the folder where the eclipse.exe was
and execute .\eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me so in the end created backup of .metadata and then .metadata->.plugins.->org.eclipse.core.resources.->.projects and there started removing projects one by one. One project was creating the problems for me. Also had -clean -clearPersistedState in eclipse.ini .

Answer (score 1):

Warning : deleting *.metadata* also deletes projects setups. So this worked for me:

1. cmd
2. cd eclipse folder
3. .\eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState

Answer (score 0):

if you delete the .metadata folder remember to import and reconfigure your workspace