# Eclipse runs in background when specific workspace selected

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

When I start Eclipse with a workspace called "workspace", works fine. But when I start Eclipse with another workspace called "133", Eclipse doesn't seem to start. If I try it again, an error "workspace cannot be created or already in use" occurs.

However, the task manager says that Eclipse is running, but in the background.

[image]

How can I prevent Eclipse to run in the background, so that I can use it again?

I work with Eclipse Neon on Windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a workspace in eclipse that does not open anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361376/how-to-fix-a-workspace-in-eclipse-that-does-not-open-anymore) or of [How to recover corrupted Eclipse workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950476/how-to-recover-corrupted-eclipse-workspace)

Comment: Start eclipse from command line and choose the workspace that is creating the issue. Look for any useful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue, the issue is resolved by opening the STS with new workspace location and existing code import here.