# Valgrind hangs when launching delegate

Tags: c++, eclipse, valgrind, ubuntu-14.04

I am running valgrind on Eclipse Luna and it hangs at 78% when launching a delegate.  I suspected my workspace has been corrupted as was in [this case](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/42413/).  So I cleaned the project and deleted the .snap and workbench.xmi files done in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950476/how-to-recover-corrupted-eclipse-workspace).  The problem still persists however.

I am running Eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04 in Orcale's Virtualbox VM.

Comment: "deletegate" ? You may want to check your spelling, because this doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: You're right. I meant delegate.  It still hangs but does complete the profiling today.  I am not sure what changed.